# Adding rows to a table with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and I'm trying to use Angular to handle adding/deleting rows in the table. I've created a service to handle the storage of the row data, but I can't get the view to update when new data is inserted into the model.

Here's a snippet of code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vksgsi7ixGKXwuNhykU7?p=preview

Here's the Javascript code:

```
var myModule = angular.module( "myApp", [] );

myModule.service( 'myService', [ '$rootScope', function( $rootScope ) {

    var service = {
        rows: ['a', 'b'],

        addRow: function(obj) {
            service.rows.push( obj );
            $rootScope.$broadcast('rows.update');
        }

    };

    return service;

}] );

myModule.controller( "myController", [ '$scope', 'myService', function( $scope, myService ) {
    var controller = this;

    controller.rows = myService.rows;

    $scope.$on( 'rows.update', function( event ) {
      console.log('received an update event. rows.length = ' + controller.rows.length);
        controller.rows = myService.rows;
    });

}] );

myModule.directive( "newRowButton", [ 'myService', function( myService ) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            element.bind( "click", function() {
                myService.addRow( 'c' );
            });
        }
    };
}] );
```

And the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as controller">
<div>
  <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in controller.rows">
                <td>hello</td>
                <td>{{row}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button new-row-button>New</button>
</div>
</body>
```

I can see (via the console.log statement) that new entries are being inserted into the row data array, but new rows aren't being created in the view.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically if u change in the view within a directive i can advise you to use the `$scope.$apply() -function` .It will update the view for sure. Here is the line where you have to change :

```
scope.$apply(myService.addRow( 'c' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call scope.$apply(); Clicking on the button will add a row c, but you cannot add any more rows as the ng-repeat will complain about duplicates. Here is what you need:

```
myModule.directive( "newRowButton", [ 'myService', function( myService ) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            element.bind( "click", function() {
                myService.addRow( 'c' );
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}] );
```